# A wrapper to try numba

Tags: python, pdb, numba

I wrote this wrapper to use numba or not depending on availability ("Can `numba` be imported?") and user settings ("Does `numba_enabled()` return True?").

This is particularly useful for testing, where I want to run tests with and without numba.

```
def try_numba_autojit(func):
    def func_(*args):
        if numba_enabled():
            try:
                import numba
            except:
                pass
            else:
                return numba.autojit(func)(*args)
        return func(*args)
    return func_
```

The Problem: The wrapper is causing functions which otherwise work to throw this error:

```
*** OverflowError: can't convert negative value to unsigned char
```

If I set `try_numba_autojit = numba.autojit`, overriding the wrapper, there is no error. I conclude that *args might be doing something that numba doesn't like.

In pdb, I have tried unpacking the args manually:

```
(Pdb) numba.autojit(func)
<specializing numba function(<function _refine at 0xa53ec6c>)>
(Pdb) numba.autojit(func)(*args)
*** OverflowError: can't convert negative value to unsigned char

(Pdb) numba.autojit(func)(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6])
*** OverflowError: can't convert negative value to unsigned char
```

which gives the same error.

Is there a recommended define a function like `try_numba_autojit` to avoid upsetting numba?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why what you're doing isn't working, but if you can do with testing for numba-availibility/enability at wrapping time, instead of function-call time, this might work (untested, sorry)

```
def try_numba_autojit():
    if numba_enabled():
        try:
            import numba
            return numba.autojit
        except ImportError:
            pass
    return lambda func: func
```

and use like:

```
@try_numba_autojit()
def f(a,b,c): ...
```

Comment: That does work (it's what I tried first, in fact) but I'd like to have the ability to use numba or not after import using ``enable_numba()`` and ``disable_numba()``. If that's not possible, I'm hoping to eventually understand why. Thanks for this fine answer though.